# Reordering in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, acts-as-list

sometime we need to reorder our resources and [acts_as_list](http://swanandp.github.com/acts_as_list/) is really useful for this task. My question is:
What is the best way to implement reordering of some resources in [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) framework.

*I know that there is no "best way" but I guess that all replies are welcome so people will be able to find all kind of answers for this kind of question.*

---

I've written down one of the possible solutions myself, and it's using jquery with drag&drop, but isn't working with filters, scopes and sorting. Maybe there's a reason to dedicate separate view for drag&drop reordering, or maybe someone have done a different UI with checkboxes, buttons, etc…

Please share!

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions is described in [Sortable lists with acts_as_list and ActiveAdmin](http://mossity.com/2011/07/08/sortable-lists-with-actsaslist-and-activeadmin/). The solution is very nice, and all I can add from myself is a bit different serialization function and some more cosmetic stuff:

First of all, I've thought that that it'll be more efficient to move the desired resource into specified position instead of shifting all that are after it. Here is my updated `update` function:

```
$("#shows tbody").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui){
    var request
    if (ui.item.next().length == 0)
      request = {method: 'move_to_bottom', target: ui.item.find("span.show").data("id")}
    else
      request = {method: 'put_at_index', data: ui.item.next().find("span.show").data("id"), target: ui.item.find("span.show").data("id")}
    $.ajax({
      url: "/admin/shows/sort",
      type: 'post',
      headers: {
            'X-Transaction': 'sort shows',
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
      data: request,
      complete: function(){
        $(".paginated_collection").effect("highlight");
        repaintTable();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

As you can see, I either send a `put_at_index` method with the data what to put and on what item's index (that's actually the item below the one we have dragged) and if it was dragged to the bottom of the list, and there's nothing below it (after it) then I just send a `move_to_bottom` method with the data what to move to the bottom.

The `sort` action was also altered and now works like this:

```
collection_action :sort, :method => :post do
  case params[:method]
    when 'move_to_bottom'
      Show.find(params[:target]).move_to_bottom
    when 'put_at_index'
      Show.find(params[:target]).insert_at(Show.find(params[:data]).position)
  end
  head 200
end
```

So it just uses `insert_at` and `move_to_bottom` methods of acts_as_list.

Also I've added a `repaintTable` so the odd and even rows have still different colors after the switch and I call it after the ajax request is complete.

```
function repaintTable()
{
  $("#shows tr").removeClass('even odd');
  $("#shows tr").filter(":odd").addClass('odd');
  $("#shows tr").filter(":even").addClass('even');
}
```

The drawback is that it works bad with scopes, filters and sorting by some column.